# Can I force a grails dev server to reload when any code recompiles?

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, compilation

The short question is: can I force the Grails 2.2 dev server to reload (reinitializing all singleton services, etc) whenever new code is hot-compiled and swapped in?

Let me make the question clear with an example. Let's say that

1. I have a singleton-scoped service called `MyService`. In its `@PostConstruct` function, it initializes a new object of type `Helper` (and holds on to the reference).
2. I `run-app` in dev mode, test things out, and then...
3. I edit the source code for `Helper.groovy`

What happens next is:

- Grails automatically recompiles `Helper.groovy`
- Grails swaps the new code into the running dev server
- But the new `Helper` code isn't **called** because the already-instantiated `MyService` object already has a handle on an instance of the old kind.

My current workaround  is to *keep a **dependency graph in my head**, and `touch` or trivially modify `MyService` every time I change one of its dependencies*.  But I'd much rather force the dev server to reload completely whenever new code is swapped in.

So... **is it possible to force the dev server to reload whenever any code changes**?

And a **bonus question**: when I change a Domain Object, the only way I can force the dev server to "follow" those changes is to `stop-app`, `clean`, and `run-app` manually.  Can I automate this to happen whenever it's required?

Thanks!

Comment: Found a way out for your problem, see "CRITICAL UPDATE" to my answer below. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## CRITICAL UPDATE

I was able to get what you were looking for. Laying it down step wise:

**REQUIREMENT** -
When `Helper` class is modified, `service` class should be refreshed to refer to the modified helper class.

**SETUP**

```
//src/groovy
class SampleHelper {
    String name = 'Heisenberg'

    def sayMyName(){
        "$name"
    }
}

//grails-app/service
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct
class SampleService {
    String cachedName

    @PostConstruct
    def initIt(){
        cachedName = new SampleHelper().sayMyName()
    }

    def serviceMethod() {
        cachedName
    }
}

//controller
class SampleController {
    def sampleService

    def index() {
        render sampleService.serviceMethod()
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**
When `name` in helper class is updated to `Gus`, the class refreshes but the service class is still referencing to the old instance of `SampleHelper`. Result, name still shows `Heisenberg`.

**SOLUTION**

- Watch the helper class.
- Refresh the service class `onChange` of helper class.

This can be achieved by using the [Pluginator plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/pluginator) in the application which gives the flexibility to watch a file and do something `onChange` event.

- Install the plugin.
- Add the below `ApplicationPlugin.groovy` under `grails-app/conf`.

as

```
class ApplicationPlugin {
    //Watch the helper class
    def watchedResources = "file:./src/groovy/**/*.groovy"

    //Re-Register the bean (service class) onChange of Helper Class
    //This can be generalized more.
    def onChange = { event ->
        if (event.source) {
            def beans = beans {
                sampleService(SampleService) { bean ->
                    bean.autowire =  true
                }
            }
            if (event.ctx) {
                event.ctx.registerBeanDefinition(
                        "sampleService",
                        beans.getBeanDefinition("sampleService"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- **PROBLEM STATEMENT** should be fixed after the above steps followed.

**NOTE**

- This process might be resource intensive if followed for all classes and artefacts.

---

## OLD & Valid Answer

I am unable to recreate your problem in Grails 2.2.0. Below is the setup I have (correct me if I am wrong anywhere):

```
//src/groovy
class MyHelper{
    def sayMyName(){
        "Heisenberg"
    }
}

//service
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct
class MyService {
    def myHelper

    @PostConstruct
    def initIt(){
        myHelper = new MyHelper()
    }

    def serviceMethod() {
        myHelper.sayMyName()
    }
}

//controller (to test)
class MyController {
    def myService

    def index() {
        render myService.serviceMethod()
    }
}
```

**Steps:**

- Run the initial setup. (`run-app`)
- Hit the controller to see "Heisenberg"
- Modify `MyHelper.sayMyName()` to return "Walter White" instead of "Heisenberg"
- Hit the controller again and see "Walter White"

**Observation:**

- I would rather make `MyHelper` a bean and use (inject) it in the service class for use.

Entry to `resources.groovy` as follows:

```
beans = {
    myHelper(com.example.MyHelper)
}
```

Service class becomes:

```
class MyService {
    def myHelper

    def serviceMethod() {
        myHelper.sayMyName()
    }
}
```

- Now, referring to field in `MyHelper` in the service class will give an issue because the bean has been instantiated already in the container

**Regarding Bonus Question:**

I am unable to recreate the problem either in Grails 2.2.0

```
//domain
class MyDomain {
    String name
}

//controller action
def add(){
    def myDomain = new MyDomain(name: 'Testing').save(flush: true)
    render myDomain.properties
}
```

- Change the domain, add `String email`
- Save Domain class.
- Modify action to add `email` in `MyDomain` (obviously a new row will be created).
- Save Controller.
- Hit the action again.
- See the result.

Comment: So first off, thanks for an extremely thorough response! Here's a modification to your code that makes it break: in MyService, do: 
```
String cachedName;
@PostConstruct
    def initIt(){
        cachedName = new MyHelper().sayName()
    }
```

I agree this is a bit contrived, but it's analogous to my scenario.

Comment: @Bosh Well you have mentioned earlier that you are just holding on to the reference of the helper (not accessing any property). The way you are mentioning right now you can never access the latest helper, since the service (a kind of refreshing spring bean) is already created as singleton which only **refreshes** when its source changes. My bucks are for injecting the helper in the service class and using `sayMyName()` whenever required in it. (Modify `sayMyName()` accessing its fields).

Comment: I definitely take your point about refactoring! (And I will, though my actual code isn't much like what we're talking about here.)  When you said "the service... is already created as singleton which only refreshes when its source changes" -- that's exactly what my question is getting at: is there a way for me to force **everything** to refresh anytime any code recompiles?

Comment: @Bosh I am not aware of a particular way to reload all the files on change of one file. It is quite obvious this will be resource intensive and does not add value in my development if I am working on something. In case I want to trigger something on file change, I would look at using [Gant Scripts](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingGantScripts) and try to hook into events. I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: @Bosh Looks like I am aware of it now. Thanks for making me think about it. :)